# Using DLL in java through JNA

Tags: java, .net, jna

I am using dll in java using JNA, but i am getting below error

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetStatus': The specified procedure could not be found.**

Not getting how to resolve this issue?

Please help.

Here is java code

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;



 /** Simple example of native library declaration and usage. */
public class First {
     public interface TEST extends Library {
       public String GetStatus();
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      TEST obj = (TEST ) Native.loadLibrary("TEST ", TEST .class);

       System.out.println( obj.GetStatus());

   }
}
```

Comment: What is the native-langugage return type for GetStatus()?

Comment: Have you read the corresponding [FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-library-mapping-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)?

Comment: @Andy Thomas: its String

Comment: Are you trying to call a .Net library through JNA? You can't do that directly.

Comment: Yes, Can you please guide me how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This Nugget is super easy to use and works perfectly. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

You need Visual Studio 2012 (express).
Once installed, just add  `[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]` before any static function you want to export. That's it!

**Example:**

**C#**

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static int YourFunction(string data)
{
     /*Your code here*/
     return 1;
}
```

**Java**

Add the import at the top:

```
   import com.sun.jna.Native;
```

Add the interface in your class. Its your C# function name preceded by the letter "I":

```
  public interface IYourFunction extends com.sun.jna.Library
    {
       public int YourFunction(String tStr);
    };
```

Call your DLL where you need it in your class:

```
IYourFunction iYourFunction = (IYourFunction )Native.loadLibrary("full or relative path to DLL withouth the .dll extention", IYourFunction.class);//call JNA
        System.out.println("Returned: " + IYourFunction.YourFunction("some parameter"));
```

EDIT:
If the DLL is 32bit, the JDK/JRE has to be 32bit as well. Add the following check to your code:

```
if(!System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("x86")) {
            throw new Exception(".NET DLL " + "32bits JRE/JDK is required. Currently using " + System.getProperty("os.arch") + ".\r\nTry changing your PATH environement variable.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I tried that method and I'm getting  [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetDocumentsInStudentFolder': The specified procedure could not be found.]. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WhoCares If your DLL is 32bits, make sure the JDK/JRE is 32bit as well. A 64bit will have trouble to run a 32bit DLL.

Comment: @WhoCares
   I have added this code:
    if(!System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("x86")) {
            throw new Exception(".NET DLL " + "32bits JRE/JDK is     required. Currently using " + System.getProperty("os.arch") +  ".\r\nTry changing your PATH environement variable.");
            }